# Perl ejecutar SQLCMD con variables

Tags: sql-server, perl

Necesito pasarle variables al commando SQLCMD. Tengo el siguiente script:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use Config::IniFiles;
my $TODAY = strftime "%Y%m%d", localtime;
my $cfg = Config::IniFiles->new( -file => 'test.ini' );
my @db = $cfg->Sections;

for my $dbs (@db){
  my $IP=$cfg->val($dbs,'ip');
  my $PORT=$cfg->val($dbs,'port');
  my $USER=$cfg->val($dbs,'user');
  my $PASS=$cfg->val($dbs,'pass');
  my $DB=$cfg->val($dbs,'pass');
  my $MOTOR=$cfg->val($dbs,'motor');
  my $INSTANCIA=$cfg->val($dbs,'instancia');
  my $PATH=$cfg->val($dbs,'path');
  my $DUMP=$PATH . "Backup_Test_" . $TODAY . ".bak";
  `sqlcmd -S $IP,$PORT -U $USER -P $PASS -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [$DB] TO DISK='$DUMP'"}`;
  if($? == 0){
    print "0\n";
  }
  else{
    print "Error\n";
  }
 }
```

Como lo hago para que el sqlcmd tome los valores de estas variables. He probado con varias combinaciones pero sigo sin poder realizar el respaldo de base de datos y obtengo un 0 como resultado osea se ejecuto bien el comando pero el dump no se genera ¿...?.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo, este script lee la configuración desde un archivo externo, el 'test.ini' (en formato ini, claro), así que es ahí donde tienes que hacer los cambios.

El formato ini es muy sencillo: secciones que comienzan así:

[seccion]

seguidas luego de parejas clave=valor

Más información en
https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::IniFiles#FILE-FORMAT